# How to Select Multiple XML tags as XElement By attatribute value?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

How to select Multiple **XML Tags as XElement**, filtering based on same attribute.
I have Below code i want to select tags with are having **action=true**

```
<root>
  <first action="true">
    <path>E:\Myfolder</path>
  </first>
  <second>
    <path>C:\Users\</path>
  </second>
  <third action="true">
    <name>Mytasks</name>
  </third>
</root>
```

and Output shout be like this

```
  <first action="true">
    <path>E:\Myfolder</path>
  </first>
  <third action="true">
    <name>Mytasks</name>
  </third>
```

anybody please help me. I used *FirstorDefault(*) But i am getting only one record among all

Comment: Did you try XPath?

Comment: Show what you have tried. Also If you want all records why use `FirstOrDefault`?.

Comment: i tried all linq Functions. But FirstOrDefault() only i am getting values. so i want to came to ask the community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This .

```
$(path).find('root').find('[action="true"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

`xd = XDocument.Load("XML FILE PATH");
 xe = xd.Root;
IEnumerable<XElement> oColl = from x in xe.Descendants() where ((string)x.Attribute("action")).equals("true")  select x;`